# html2canvas saving canvas images with extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I have a web page with button onclick on that button a screenshot of this page should be taken and downloaded with (.jpg) extension.
to do that I use the following code:

```js
$("#Finish").on('click', function () {
// take a screenshot and save it.
html2canvas(element, {
 onrendered: function (canvas) {
  $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
  getCanvas = canvas;
    DownloadImage();
 }
});
});

function DownloadImage() {
var imageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
var newData = imageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
   window.open(newData);
}
```

when i click the button:

[image: show image]

As you see I have image with "download" Name without any extension.
I need to download the image with specific name and extension for example "myImage.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the button into a `<a>` tag, you should be able to use the download attribute.

```
$('#image-link').attr('href', 'data:image/png;base64,<data>").attr('download', 'filename.png');
```

Haven't played around with it too much myself but it is said to work in Firefox, Chrome and Edge: https://caniuse.com/#feat=download